# Array.prototype.filter not working as intended

Tags: javascript, algorithm, filter, async-await, es6-promise

I am making a sample application using the **star wars API** and need to filter the data using a select field and a button in html5. I have a function called `filterBySelections`, which uses `array.filter`.  The functions should:

- get the selection options
- if an option selected then find all of from the parameter object.

I tried using `array.includes` to run through the filter method
using the `array[index]` within `arr.filter`.

```html
 <select name="" id="option-1" tabindex="2">
      <option >CR90 Corvette</option>
      <option >V-wing</option>
      <option >Belbullab </option>
      <option >Starfighter</option>
      <option >Jedi Interceptor</option>
      <option >Star Destroyer</option>
      <option >Trade Fedaration Cruiser</option>
      <option >Solar Sailer</option>
      <option >Republic Attack Cruiser</option>
      <option >A-wing</option>
      <option >B-wing</option>
      <option >Naboo Figther</option>
      <option >Millenium Falcon</option>
    </select>
```

```js
//lib.js

function filterBySelections(obj = []) {
  var select_1 = Array.from(document.getElementById("option-1"));
  var select_2 = Array.from(document.getElementById("option-2"));
  var mylist;
  for (var i = 0; i < select_1.length; i++) {
    var opt1 = select_1[i],
      opt2 = select_2[i];

    if (opt1.selected && opt2.selected) {
      mylist = obj.filter((data, index, array) => {
        if (array[index].name !== opt1.textContent) return false;
        if (array[index].name !== opt2.textContent) return false;
        return array[index].name == (opt1 && opt2).textContent;
      });
    }
  }
return mylist
}


//compare.js

compareButton.addEventListener("click", initApp);

function initApp() {
  api
    .getStarShips()
    .then(response => quick_sort(response))
    .then(result =>
      compareButton.addEventListener("click", filterBySelections(result))
    ).then (data=>console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: Why `array[index]` instead of `data` ?

Comment: I was overthinking in the senario

Comment: I was testing a lot of content whilst searching through mdn and w3schools docs

Answer (score 0):

```
  return array[index].name == (opt1 && opt2).textContent;
```

Is equal to

```
 return array[index].name == opt2.textContent;
```

as `opt1` is *truthy*, thus `&&` evaluates to the right hand side, ... and thats probably not what you wanted. You already covered both cases in the if statements above, so just

```
 return true;
```

Or just use some boolean algebra:

```
  mylist = obj.filter((data) => data.name === opt1.textContent || data.name === opt2.textContent);
```